# Java WebStart and endorsed directories

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, endorsed

How do I specify in java webstart .jnlp file, that some of my jars are overriding the JRE builtin implementations? Just like the endorsed lib property on a regular application.

Comment: There might be a different way of doing a .jnlp implementation by using YAJSW.  I would recommend looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no way to define endorsed dirs in web start.

Even defining the java.endorsed.dirs property to some local directory doesn't work. Probably java sets the variables after the runtime is already up.

Two possible solutions to this:

1. From the web start application, only run command line java with java.endorsed.dirs and all the dependencies (classpath & args) the web start application would do. You have to handle jnlp jars updates each time.
2. At first run require user or do automatic copy of required jar to JRE/lib/endorsed directory. And then require restart of web start application. Note that this method will put endorsed jars for all java application that will run with the JRE.