# Java 7 update 55 JacORB error when running via WebStart

Tags: java, java-web-start, classnotfoundexception, jacorb

Since updating to Java 7 update 55, I'm not able to run my WebStart java application.

This application worked fine under Java 7 update 51 when launched via WebStart.

It also works with update 55 when launched outside of WebStart.

Any suggestions for further investigation points?

```
org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation org.jacorb.orb.ORBSingleton  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.create_impl_with_systemclassloader(Unknown Source)
    at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.jacorb.orb.CDRInputStream.<init>(CDRInputStream.java:186)
    at org.jacorb.orb.etf.ProfileBase.initFromProfileData(ProfileBase.java:252)
    at org.jacorb.orb.etf.ProfileBase.demarshal(ProfileBase.java:172)
    at org.jacorb.orb.etf.FactoriesBase.demarshal_profile(FactoriesBase.java:124)
    at org.jacorb.orb.ParsedIOR.decode(ParsedIOR.java:235)
    at org.jacorb.orb.ParsedIOR.parse_stringified_ior(ParsedIOR.java:460)
    at org.jacorb.orb.ParsedIOR.parse(ParsedIOR.java:375)
    at org.jacorb.orb.ParsedIOR.<init>(ParsedIOR.java:192)
    at org.jacorb.orb.ORB.string_to_object(ORB.java:1824)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jacorb.orb.ORBSingleton
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    ... 56 more
```

**Edit 12th June 2014**

Looks like this issue has been fixed here:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8042789

This will hopefully be included in the next CPU on July 15th

Looks like the change that caused this issue was reverted so it now uses the current thread classloader again.

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/corba/rev/009fc3f785a9

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).  Then check the [Bug Database](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/) & if you don't see anything, raise a new one.

Comment: same for jdk 1.8.0_05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this issue is included in java 7 update 65.
It now works as before.

Answer (score 2):

I've opened a bug to Java for this (Review ID: JI-9011898). The issue is that in the org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init() method the system class loader is forced to use, while in the past the current thread's class loader was used.

UPDATE: a valid workaround is copying the JacORB jars inside the /jre/lib/endorsed folder, so these classes can be loaded outside the webstart class loader.
See [Java WebStart and endorsed directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842779/java-webstart-and-endorsed-directories) and [Java 7u55 Eclipse System Fragment Classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225144/java-7u55-eclipse-system-fragment-classloader) for details.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected a classloader issue, but didn't find evidence to back up my suspicions. Do you have a link showing the change made, and a link to the issue you've raised? Thanks

Comment: Could you link directly to the bug "JI-9011898"? I can't find it on the bug parade. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a relevant bug, targeted for fix in 7u65 or 8u11.
http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8019274

Comment: I had the same issue within and OSGi envirornment.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217131/java-7-update-55-jacorb-error-when-running-via-webstart?lq=1

Comment: UPDATE: Oracle accepted the bug. Here is the link to the description. Target version: 7u80. http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8042462

Answer (score 2):

Did some more digging and I found a commit to ORB.java that is causing the issue.

```
changeset:   817:a8d27c3fc4e4
tag:         jdk7u55-b05
user:        msheppar
date:        Tue Jan 21 12:46:58 2014 +0000
summary:     8025005: Enhance CORBA initializations
```

This commit changed the way the ORB Singleton class was created.  Instead of using the Thread context class loader it is now hard coded to use the SystemClassLoader.

```
-                singleton = create_impl(className);
+                singleton = create_impl_with_systemclassloader(className);
         }
     }
     return singleton;
 }

+   private static ORB create_impl_with_systemclassloader(String className) {
+
+        try {
+            ReflectUtil.checkPackageAccess(className);
+            ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
+            Class<org.omg.CORBA.ORB> orbBaseClass = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.class;
+            Class<?> singletonOrbClass = Class.forName(className, true, cl).asSubclass(orbBaseClass);
+            return (ORB)singletonOrbClass.newInstance();
+        } catch (Throwable ex) {
+            SystemException systemException = new INITIALIZE(
+                "can't instantiate default ORB implementation " + className);
+            systemException.initCause(ex);
+            throw systemException;
+        }
+    }
```

Putting the JacORB classes on the endorsed dirs or ext classpath is a valid work around.  However, this definitely changes previous behavior.

Has anyone filed a bug for it?

**--- UPDATE ---**

There is a bug related to this issue:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8042789

It is available in Java 8u22.
https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

Comment: I think there are a few of us that have raised review requests with Oracle, I haven't heard anything back yet. (Review ID: JI-9011905 submitted on 23rd April)

Answer (score 0):

There is now a release note about this change in 7u55, see:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u55-relnotes-2177812.html

Answer (score 0):

The (recently updated, as this information wasn' there before) release notes mentioned by user3054250 (thank you for this) point to another possible workaround.

Specifying only the `org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass` property but **omiting** `org.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass` works in my CORBA/Webstart application together with JacORB 3.4.

it doesn't work with OpenORB (as OpenORB checks for the "right" instance of ORBSingleton) so I have to upgrade my application to JacORB.

Edit: With OpenORB (and I suppose with many other ORBs too) there is the same problem as mentioned by the questioner - a ClassCastException because ORB classes not visible to the SystemClassLoader in Webstart Applications but ORBSingleton loaded using SystemClassLoader now.

The difference to JacORB is that OpenORB checks if the ORBSingleton is of the right type when the ORB gets instantiated - which means (depending on the version) e.g. if it is of type org.openorb.CORBA.ORBSingleton.
For me it is no problem to switch to JacORB but I wanted to mention that the approach of omiting ORBSingleton setting doesn't help with any ORB but for the questioner it could be a better solution than putting the ORB stuff into .../endorsed

Answer (score 0):

Can you say a bit more about the problem with OpenORB? Is it a ClassCastException or other error? A stack trace would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant JacORB issue is http://www.jacorb.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=984 (for x-ref purposes).

If anyone has a sample test case they wouldn't mind uploading to that ticket it would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Moving to openjdk worked for me. I'm going to have to find a proper solution but that was my work around till I can redo my code.