# Java 7u55 on mac breaks SWT Web Start app

Tags: java, macos, swt, java-web-start

We have happily been deploying our cross-platform SWT app with Web Start for years. On the mac we had to switch from using `-XStartOnFirst` to using the `com.apple.concurrent.Dispatch` class to get SWT to run in the first thread.

Java 7 update 55 breaks our app again, and again it seems to be Web Start related.

The app starts and displays all windows, but all interface interactions don't have an effect until you click some other widget. For example, if I click a tab to bring it to foreground, I have to then click another widget to finally get the first action to fire. This is probably threading related, like most SWT/Web Start problems but I have no workaround for this problem other than stay away from 7u55. Has anybody experienced this problem and found a workaround?

EDIT: It seems the problem stems from our use of JNA, which we use to get the idle time from the OS using CGSSecondsSinceLastInputEvent. I get a NullPointerException in JNLPClassloader in the logs. If I comment out the code that uses JNA, the problem goes away. Since Oracle seems to be paranoid with security these last months, I'm guessing there is a problem with the jna jar. I sign all jars with the same cert, but maybe there is a new manifest attribute that I should be looking at. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: And your question is? Did you post a bug report?

Comment: Edited the original post to actually ask a question. I haven't filed a bug report since I'm not sure if it is a bug or simply that the current way to run SWT apps in Web Start have changed. It's obvious that SWT is in an arms race with Oracle on the Mac, and SWT seems to be losing. Almost every update of Java makes it harder and harder to run SWT apps, at least in Web Start.

Comment: Might be similar to this bug, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217131/java-7-update-55-jacorb-error-when-running-via-webstart/23238815#23238815